# UNION of select fields from multiple tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to create multiple queries that involve some sort of UNION. The only way I have been able to figure it out is below.  Is there any way I can streamline the process so I don't need a separate union for each table? (I have about 50 tables and don't want to have to do this for each)  - Working with an Access db

SELECT Header1, Header2, header 3, header 4 
FROM score_ADACOMPT 
UNION

SELECT Header1, Header2, header 3, header 4 
FROM score_ADADESG 
UNION

SELECT Header1, Header2, header 3, header 4 
FROM Score_API 
UNION

SELECT Header1, Header2, header 3, header 4 
FROM score_COMPCAC 
UNION

SELECT Header1, Header2, header 3, header 4 
FROM Score_CRV 
UNION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will run into a few roadblocks with that approach.  I've never found official documentation on it, but Access can only handle so many UNION operations at a time.  It seems to depend on how complex the operations and queries are. You could try to write VBA to create the UNION query syntax, and see if Access can handle it. If it does, then consider yourself lucky.

Alternatively, you might consider creating a table to hold those values, and run append query's to load the data into that table.  This has pluses and minuses, depending on the application environment, and what you're planning to do with the data once it's combined.

Example to Loop Through DAO TableDefs and Create a UNION query:

```
Public Sub TestIt()

    BuildUNIONQuery "UNIONTest"
End Sub

Public Sub BuildUNIONQuery(saveQueryName As String)
'builds a large union query for queries starting with "score_" and contains fields:  Header1, Header2, header 3, header 4

    Dim qryStr As String
    Dim tDef As DAO.TableDef
    Dim qDef As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim db As DAO.Database

    Set db = Access.CurrentDb
    qryStr = ""

    For Each tDef In db.TableDefs

        If tDef.Name Like "score_*" Then

            qryStr = qryStr & "SELECT [Header 1], [Header 2], [header 3], [header 4] "
            qryStr = qryStr & "FROM [" & tDef.Name & "] "
            qryStr = qryStr & "UNION "

        End If
    Next tDef

    'remove last UNION from string
    If Len(qryStr) > 0 Then
        qryStr = Left(qryStr, Len(qryStr) - 6)
    End If

    If QueryExists(saveQueryName) Then 'query exits update SQL for current item

        Set qDef = db.QueryDefs(saveQueryName)

        qDef.SQL = qryStr
        db.QueryDefs.Refresh

    Else

        Set qDef = db.CreateQueryDef(saveQueryName, qryStr)

        db.QueryDefs.Refresh
    End If
End Sub

Public Function QueryExists(qName As String) As Boolean
'determine if query name already exists in the database

    Dim qDef As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim db As DAO.Database

    Set db = Access.CurrentDb
    QueryExists = False

    For Each qDef In db.QueryDefs
        If qDef.Name = qName Then
            QueryExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next qDef
```

End Function

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out a way to write VBA to create the UNION query syntax.  I am pretty new with VBA and SQL (pretty much any type of code).  I have used my method for the UNION of up to 17 queries, but it is very tedious.  Once the data is combined I create a "master sheet" by pulling from the original data and the combined data - lots of tedious work but it needs to get done.

Comment: Well I hit a road block.  I am not gettings "query is too complex" or "system resource exceeded".  I am really getting stuck here.  The data I have needs to be updated likely on a monthly basis so I can't just export to excel and the combine the results separately otherwise it would take too much time.

Comment: The example should get you started looping through Tables/Queries to construct a large UNION query, or to execute pre-defined append queries.  The code will require some modifications depending on your exact requirements.  Hope it helps.